# Send sms in Cordova 3.4

Tags: java, android, html, cordova

I am new in cordova 3.4. I want to write send sms app. I get SMSPlugin from github but i want to write this myself. I write a html file like this and copy in root/www and i write a java script file in root/www/js. but when i run the app, i don't see button in the page! Why? What is problem? How can i write this app?

And i change name of java file(Activity) from AndroidManifest manually to my class, this is not a problem, Yes? and i changed 'id' in widget tag from config.xml to my package manually.

index.html:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>


    <script type="text/javascript">
   var txtMSG = "";
        function onDeviceReady(){
            document.getElementById("deviceName").innerHTML= device.model;
            document.getElementById("version").innerHTML= device.cordova;
            document.getElementById("mobilePlatform").innerHTML= device.platform;
            document.getElementById("platformVersion").innerHTML= device.version;
            document.getElementById("uuid").innerHTML= device.uuid;
            document.getElementById("sendSMS").style.display="block";
        }
        function displayTextMessage(msg){
            alert(msg);
            $('#text-messages').prepend('<div>' + msg + '</div>');
        } 
        function sendConsole(){
            var message = "This_is_a_test"
            DeviceInfo.SendConsole({text: message}, function(){
                alert("success");
            }, function(){
                alert("fail");
            });
        }
        function SendSMS(){
            console.log("-------------------Start----------------------");
            DeviceInfo.SendSMS({phoneNumber:[document.getElementById('cellNumber').value], text: document.getElementById('textMessage').value}, function(){
                alert("success");
            }, function(){
                alert("fail");
            });
            console.log("---------------------End--------------------");
        }
        /** Called when browser load this page*/
        function init(){
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }
    </script>


</head>

<body>
    <input id="sendSMS" style="display:none" type="button" ontouchend="SendSMS()" onclick="SendSMS()" value="Send SMS To:" />
    <!-- <button onClick="SendSMS();">Send SMS</button> <br> -->
    <input id="cellNumber" type="text" style="width:100%" value="9126012134" onclick="this.select()" ontouchend="this.select()" />
    <textarea id="textMessage" style="width:100%; height:100px">Plugin Example</textarea>

    <input id="sendConsole" style="display:none" type="button" ontouchend="sendConsole()" onclick="sendConsole()" value="Send Console Log" />
    <div id="text-messages" style="border:solid 1px #efefef; padding 10px"></div>
</body>



 </html>
```

DeviceInfo.js:

```
  var DeviceInfo = function () { };

  DeviceInfo.callMethod = function (methodName, content, success, fail) {
return PhoneGap.exec(function (args) {
    success(args);
}, function (args) {
    fail(args);
}, 'DeviceInfo', methodName, [content]);
 }

DeviceInfo.GetPhoneNumber = function (content, success, fail) {
  return DeviceInfo.callMethod('getPhoneNumber', content, success, fail);
};

DeviceInfo.SendSMS = function (content, success, fail) {
  return DeviceInfo.callMethod('SendSMS', content, success, fail);
};

DeviceInfo.SendConsole = function (content, success, fail) {
   return DeviceInfo.callMethod('SendConsole', content, success, fail);
};
```

Thanks for advises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin on ghithub developed by javatechig [here](https://github.com/javatechig/phonegap-sms-plugin) but only work with old cordova/phonegap version. This fork https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin works with recent version of cordova and is updated frequently. Read the "readme.md" for example and more informations.

> This Android Phonegap plugin allows you to easily send SMS in android using both native SMS Manager or by invoking the default android SMS app

Comment: Thanks for reply, I solve problem but i face to another problem :( I can't call execute() method for connection between js and native android. Why? For this , i need to a permission or plugin?